# Как принять сложный json в Spring (CrudRepository.save() )

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

```
public interface SurveyRepository extends JpaRepository<Survey, Long> {}
```

-

```
@Entity
public class Survey {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@NonNull
private String title;
private String content;
private String date;
List<Field> fields; //ругается на List
}
```

С фронта приходит следующий json:

```
emptyItem = {
    title: 'Hello',
    content: 'heeell no',
    fields: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: '',
            voted: 0
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: '',
            voted: 0
        }
    ]
};
```

-

Проблема с сохранением поля fields: Как будет правильнее это исправить?

Думаю можно переопределить метод save() в SurveyRepository (возможно есть какие то стандартные способы).

Comment: Класс Field это созданный вами класс вашем приложении?

Comment: Возможно вам поможет массив вместо листа, если нет, то нужно будет свой парсер писать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первый вариант создать в БД дополнительную таблицу для хранения `Field` и связать с *Survey* через one-to-many

---

Второй вариант хранить список как json в БД

Анотирвать поле кастомным конвертером

```
@Convert(converter = CustomConverter.class)
private List<Field> fields;
```

Сам конвертер

```
public class CustomConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<Field>, String> {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<Field> object) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Field> convertToEntityAttribute(String data) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(data, new TypeReference<List<Field>>() {});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Боомба! Спасибо!